# Convertir Excel a JSON

Tags: javascript, datatables

Quiero cargar un DataTable con JSON, pero aun no logro siquiera convertir a JSON tengo inconvenientes no se si me faltan algunas librerías o algunas de ellas ya caducaron, en todo caso me pueden indicar la pagina donde están las librerías mas actualizadas. Estoy revisando el algoritmo pero me parece que esta ok salvo que se me escape algunos detalles que no identifico.

Me marca errores como:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
> index.html:1  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/jazo2/OneDrive/Escritorio/hoy/Datos.xlsx' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, edge.
> Datos.xlsx:1

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/read-excel-file@5.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="xlsx.full.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
  <title>Convertir Excel a JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url="Datos.xlsx";
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", url, true);
    oReq.responseType="arraybuffer"; 
    oReq.onload=function(e)
    {
        var info=readData();
        console.log(info);
        console.log("Sensor:" + info[2].Sensor);
        console.log("Dato:" + info[2].Dato);

        function readData()
        {
            var arraybuffer=oReq.response;

            var data=new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
            var arr =new Array();
            for(var i=0; i!=data.length; ++i) arr[i]=String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
            var bstr=arr.join("");

            var workbook=XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});

            var first_sheet_name=workbook.SheetNames[0];
            
            var worksheet=workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
            var info=XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true});
            return info;
        }
    }
    oReq.send();

});
```

Comment: Hola Juan, por el mensaje de error pareciera que estas abriendo el archivo en el navegador y por eso el error de CORS. Deberías usar un servidor HTTP. Saludos!

Comment: _Access to XMLHttpRequest at <ruta> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, edge_. Primero traducí el error, luego buscá acerca de CORS.

Comment: Hola estimado, inicialmente es verlo en el navegador, sin embargo el objetivo final es trasladar esos registros de JSON a un DataTable, es ahi donde pierdo el camino y no se como hacerlo